# how to go to a particular page in turn.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turn.js

i want to design a magazine i searched a lot i got the bellow code and i modified it as need. but how to searching particular page  in a magazine and can it but done with turn.js or anything else

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Using turn.js and the new zoom feature</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../extras/jquery.min.1.7.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/hash.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>

 <div id="canvas">

 <div class="zoom-icon zoom-icon-in"></div>

 <div class="magazine-viewport">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="magazine">
        <!-- Next button -->
        <div ignore="1" class="next-button"></div>
        <!-- Previous button -->
        <div ignore="1" class="previous-button"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  <!-- Thumbnails -->  
  <div class="thumbnails">
  <div>
    <ul>
        <li class="i">
                <img src="pages/1.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-1">
            <span>1</span>
        </li>   
        <li class="d">   
            <img src="pages/2.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-2">
            <img src="pages/3.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-3">
            <span>2-3</span>
        </li> 
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/4.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-4">
            <img src="pages/5.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-5">
            <span>4-5</span>
        </li>
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/6.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-6">
            <img src="pages/7.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-7">
            <span>6-7</span>
        </li>
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/8.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-8">
            <img src="pages/9.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-9">
            <span>8-9</span>
        </li>
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/10.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-10">
            <img src="pages/11.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-11">
            <span>10-11</span>
        </li>
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/12.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-12">
            <img src="pages/13.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-13">
            <span>12-13</span>
        </li>
        <li class="d">
            <img src="pages/14.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-14">
            <img src="pages/15.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-15">
            <span>14-15</span>  
        </li>
       <ul>
      <div> 
   </div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function loadApp() {

$('#canvas').fadeIn(1000);

var flipbook = $('.magazine');

// Check if the CSS was already loaded

if (flipbook.width()==0 || flipbook.height()==0) {
    setTimeout(loadApp, 10);
    return;
}

// Create the flipbook

flipbook.turn({

        // Magazine width

        width: 922,

        // Magazine height

        height: 600,

        // Duration in millisecond

        duration: 1000,

        // Hardware acceleration

        acceleration: !isChrome(),

        // Enables gradients

        gradients: true,

        // Auto center this flipbook

        autoCenter: true,

        // Elevation from the edge of the flipbook when turning a page

        elevation: 50,

        // The number of pages

        pages: 175,

        // Events

        when: {
            turning: function(event, page, view) {

                var book = $(this),
                currentPage = book.turn('page'),
                pages = book.turn('pages');

                // Update the current URI

                Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

                // Show and hide navigation buttons

                disableControls(page);


                $('.thumbnails .page-'+currentPage).
                    parent().
                    removeClass('current');

                $('.thumbnails .page-'+page).
                    parent().
                    addClass('current');



            },

            turned: function(event, page, view) {

                disableControls(page);

                $(this).turn('center');

                if (page==1) { 
                    $(this).turn('peel', 'br');
                }

            },

            missing: function (event, pages) {

                // Add pages that aren't in the magazine

                for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                    addPage(pages[i], $(this));

            }
        }

});

// Zoom.js

$('.magazine-viewport').zoom({
    flipbook: $('.magazine'),

    max: function() { 

        return largeMagazineWidth()/$('.magazine').width();

    }, 

    when: {

        swipeLeft: function() {

            $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('next');

        },

        swipeRight: function() {

            $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('previous');

        },

        resize: function(event, scale, page, pageElement) {

            if (scale==1)
                loadSmallPage(page, pageElement);
            else
                loadLargePage(page, pageElement);

        },

        zoomIn: function () {

            $('.thumbnails').hide();
            $('.made').hide();
            $('.magazine').removeClass('animated').addClass('zoom-in');
            $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-in').addClass('zoom-icon-
        out');

            if (!window.escTip && !$.isTouch) {
                escTip = true;

                $('<div />', {'class': 'exit-message'}).
                    html('<div>Press ESC to exit</div>').
                        appendTo($('body')).
                        delay(2000).
                        animate({opacity:0}, 500, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
            }
        },

        zoomOut: function () {

            $('.exit-message').hide();
            $('.thumbnails').fadeIn();
            $('.made').fadeIn();
            $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-out').addClass('zoom-
         icon-in');

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.magazine').addClass('animated').removeClass('zoom-in');
                resizeViewport();
            }, 0);

        }
    }
});

// Zoom event

if ($.isTouch)
    $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.doubleTap', zoomTo);
else
    $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.tap', zoomTo);


// Using arrow keys to turn the page

$(document).keydown(function(e){

    var previous = 37, next = 39, esc = 27;

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case previous:

            // left arrow
            $('.magazine').turn('previous');
            e.preventDefault();

        break;
        case next:

            //right arrow
            $('.magazine').turn('next');
            e.preventDefault();

        break;
        case esc:

            $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');    
            e.preventDefault();

        break;
    }
});

// URIs - Format #/page/1 

Hash.on('^page\/([0-9]*)$', {
    yep: function(path, parts) {
        var page = parts[1];

        if (page!==undefined) {
            if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                $('.magazine').turn('page', page);
        }

    },
    nop: function(path) {

        if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
            $('.magazine').turn('page', 1);
    }
});


$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeViewport();
}).bind('orientationchange', function() {
    resizeViewport();
});

// Events for thumbnails

$('.thumbnails').click(function(event) {

    var page;

    if (event.target && (page=/page-([0-9]+)/.exec($(event.target).attr('class'))) ) {

        $('.magazine').turn('page', page[1]);
    }
});

$('.thumbnails li').
    bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

        $(this).addClass('thumb-hover');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

        $(this).removeClass('thumb-hover');

    });

if ($.isTouch) {

    $('.thumbnails').
        addClass('thumbanils-touch').
        bind($.mouseEvents.move, function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

} else {

    $('.thumbnails ul').mouseover(function() {

        $('.thumbnails').addClass('thumbnails-hover');

    }).mousedown(function() {

        return false;

    }).mouseout(function() {

        $('.thumbnails').removeClass('thumbnails-hover');

    });

}


// Regions

if ($.isTouch) {
    $('.magazine').bind('touchstart', regionClick);
} else {
    $('.magazine').click(regionClick);
}

// Events for the next button

$('.next-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

    $(this).addClass('next-button-hover');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

    $(this).removeClass('next-button-hover');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

    $(this).addClass('next-button-down');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

    $(this).removeClass('next-button-down');

}).click(function() {

    $('.magazine').turn('next');

});

// Events for the next button

$('.previous-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

    $(this).addClass('previous-button-hover');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

    $(this).removeClass('previous-button-hover');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

    $(this).addClass('previous-button-down');

}).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

    $(this).removeClass('previous-button-down');

}).click(function() {

    $('.magazine').turn('previous');

});


resizeViewport();

 $('.magazine').addClass('animated');

 }

 // Zoom icon

 $('.zoom-icon').bind('mouseover', function() { 

if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
    $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
    $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

 }).bind('mouseout', function() { 

 if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
    $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
    $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

 }).bind('click', function() {

if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomIn');
else if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out')) 
    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');

 });

   $('#canvas').hide();


 // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

 yepnope({
test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
yep: ['../../lib/turn.js'],
nope: ['../../lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
both: ['../../lib/zoom.min.js', 'js/magazine.js', 'css/magazine.css'],
complete: loadApp
 });
 $(".thumbnails").turn("page",12) ;  
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

i have got this code from http://www.turnjs.com/ how to put search to go particular page in this can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is king read it first, ask questions later

`$("#flipbook").turn("page", 10);`

http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_page